# Principal Component Analysis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, octave, pca

I'm implementing PCA using eigenvalue decomposition for sparse data. I know matlab has PCA implemented, but it helps me understand all the technicalities when I write code.
I've been following the guidance from [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=bXzAlkODwa8C&lpg=PA647&dq=eigenvalue%20decomposition&pg=PA647#v=onepage&q&f=false), but I'm getting different results in comparison to built-in function princomp.

Could anybody look at it and point me in the right direction.

Here's the code:

```
function [mu, Ev, Val ] = pca(data)

% mu - mean image
% Ev - matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigen
% values Val 
% Val - eigenvalues

if nargin ~= 1
 error ('usage: [mu,E,Values] = pca_q1(data)');
end

mu = mean(data)';

nimages = size(data,2);

for i = 1:nimages
 data(:,i) = data(:,i)-mu(i);
end

L = data'*data;
[Ev, Vals]  = eig(L);    
[Ev,Vals] = sort(Ev,Vals);

% computing eigenvector of the real covariance matrix
Ev = data * Ev;

Val = diag(Vals);
Vals = Vals / (nimages - 1);

% normalize Ev to unit length
proper = 0;
for i = 1:nimages
 Ev(:,i) = Ev(:,1)/norm(Ev(:,i));
 if Vals(i) < 0.00001
  Ev(:,i) = zeros(size(Ev,1),1);
 else
  proper = proper+1;
 end;
end;

Ev = Ev(:,1:nimages);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
function [V newX D] = myPCA(X)
    X = bsxfun(@minus, X, mean(X,1));           %# zero-center
    C = (X'*X)./(size(X,1)-1);                  %'# cov(X)

    [V D] = eig(C);
    [D order] = sort(diag(D), 'descend');       %# sort cols high to low
    V = V(:,order);

    newX = X*V(:,1:end);
end
```

and an example to compare against the PRINCOMP function from the Statistics Toolbox:

```
load fisheriris

[V newX D] = myPCA(meas);
[PC newData Var] = princomp(meas);
```

---

You might also be interested in this related post about performing [PCA by SVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181593/matlab-is-running-out-of-memory-but-it-should-not-be/3181851#3181851).

Comment: I want to ask something, Is `princomp` sorts the data of `COEFF` by `latent` by default (ref: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/princomp.html)?
What is the difference between your function and `princomp`

Comment: I want to  use `coeff` and `latent` where `coeff` is sorted with `latents`. May I use the built-in function `princomp` or your `myPCA` ??

Comment: @AhsanAli: obviously as the example above shows, both functions produce same output (up to a certain precision); the columns of `COEFF` (principal components) are sorted in descending order in terms of component variance `LATENT`. Also check the last link mentioned above about performing PCA using SVD instead of EIG.. Note that [`princomp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/princomp.html) is being replaced with [`pca`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html) function in recent editions (in fact check the source code to see that calls to `princomp` are being routed to `pca` internally).

Comment: OKay, what is the difference b/w `pca` & `princomp` and also in your function `myPCA` & `PCA by SVD` ? I'm unable to differentiate b/w them? What my problem is, I want to compute `pca` of `n` matrices of `[500x3]` where `coeff` is sorted with `latents`.

Comment: @AhsanAli: just use the `pca` function, they will come out sorted as described. Like I said before, if you look at the source code (`edit princomp.m`), it is simply forwarding the call to `pca()`...

Comment: OK I GOT IT. @Amro +1

Comment: I think there is no difference b/w `pca` & `princomp` . M i right ?
and what I checked, `pca` == `princomp` but ~= `myPCA`. Y . ?

Comment: @AhsanAli: what you have to understand is that eigenvectors are defined up to a constant, meaning that if `EV` is an eigenvector, then so is `lambda*EV` for any constant `lambda`. Now since `EIG` function always returns normalized unit vectors, we are left with an arbitrary sign (`lambda=-1` or `lambda=+1`). See this post for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18152804/97160 (also checkout the links mentioned in the comments)

Comment: @AhsanAli: PCA after all is an orthogonal transformation that transforms the data to a new coordinates system (such that the data has maximum variance along the new directions in decreasing order). The principal components (columns of `COEFF` matrix) are the vectors that describe the directions of this new system. Now if `(I,J,K)` is a basis set for the vector space then so is `(a*I,b*J,c*K)`, with a correspondingly changed data coordinates (`SCORE` matrix). So eigenvectors are not unique (can be independently scaled/multiplied by a constant) as long as they span the same subspace.

Comment: I want a suggestion, as U know better `HMMs` and `statistics`, I want to train my data with `HMM` but the Gaussians of my data are too close as I get `mcr` after training `0.89`, how can I extract features of my 3-D trajectories  of length `[501x3]` or apply some statistical analysis method on that. I applied `PCA` with respective angles but it gives mcr of `0.88`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55151/discussion-between-ahsan-ali-and-amro).