# Matlab - how to compute PCA on a huge data set

Tags: matlab, pca

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MATLAB is running out of memory but it should not be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181593/matlab-is-running-out-of-memory-but-it-should-not-be)

I want to perform PCA analysis on a huge data set of points. To be more specific, I have `size(dataPoints) = [329150 132]` where `328150` is the number of data points and `132` are the number of features.

I want to extract the eigenvectors and their corresponding eigenvalues so that I can perform PCA reconstruction.

However, when I am using the `princomp` function (i.e. `[eigenVectors projectedData eigenValues] = princomp(dataPoints);` I obtain the following error :

```
>> [eigenVectors projectedData eigenValues] = princomp(pointsData);
Error using svd
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in princomp (line 86)
[U,sigma,coeff] = svd(x0,econFlag); % put in 1/sqrt(n-1) later
```

However, if I am using a smaller data set, I have no problem.

How can I perform PCA on my whole dataset in Matlab? Have someone encountered this problem?

**Edit**:

I have modified the `princomp` function and tried to use `svds` instead of `svd`, but however, I am obtaining pretty much the same error. I have dropped the error bellow :

```
Error using horzcat
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in svds (line 65)
B = [sparse(m,m) A; A' sparse(n,n)];

Error in princomp (line 86)
[U,sigma,coeff] = svds(x0,econFlag); % put in 1/sqrt(n-1) later
```

Comment: What about your progress? I wonder whether any of the answers helped with your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution based on Eigen Decomposition**

You can first compute PCA on `X'X` as @david said. Specifically, see the script below:

```
sz = [329150 132];
X = rand(sz);

[V D] = eig(X.' * X);
```

Actually, `V` holds the right singular vectors, and it holds the principal vectors if you put your data vectors in rows. The eigenvalues, `D`, are the variances among each direction. The singular vectors, which are the standard deviations, are computed as the square root of the variances:

```
S = sqrt(D);
```

Then, the left singular vectors, `U`, are computed using the formula `X = USV'`. Note that `U` refers to the principal components if your data vectors are in columns.

```
U = X*V*S^(-1);
```

Let us reconstruct the original data matrix and see the L2 reconstruction error:

```
X2 = U*S*V';
L2ReconstructionError = norm(X(:)-X2(:))
```

It is almost zero:

```
L2ReconstructionError =
  6.5143e-012
```

If your data vectors are in columns and you want to convert your data into eigenspace coefficients, you should do `U.'*X`.

This code snippet takes around 3 seconds in my moderate 64-bit desktop.

**Solution based on Randomized PCA**

Alternatively, you can use a faster approximate method which is based on randomized PCA. Please see [my answer in Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/11934/5025). You can directly compute `fsvd` and get `U` and `V` instead of using `eig`.

You may employ randomized PCA if the data size is too big. But, I think the previous way is sufficient for the size you gave.

Comment: Just for clarification, shouldn't it be "The singular *values*, which are the standard deviations"?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have a huge data set. You don't need all of the svd coefficients. In this case, use `svds` instead of `svd` :

Taken directly from Matlab help:

```
 s = svds(A,k) computes the k largest singular values and associated singular vectors of matrix A.
```

From your question, I understand that you don't call `svd` directly. But you might as well take a look at `princomp` (It is editable!) and alter the line that calls it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably needed to calculate an **n by n** matrix in your computation somehow that is to say:

```
329150 * 329150 * 8btyes ~ 866GB`
```

of space which explains why you're getting a memory error. There seems to be an efficient way to calculate pca using `princomp(X, 'econ')` which I suggest you give it a try.

More on this in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181593/matlab-is-running-out-of-memory-but-it-should-not-be?rq=1) and [mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/princomp.html?nocookie=true)..

Comment: `329150` are the number of data point. I have `1321 features. So basically I have to compute a `132 by 132` matrix.

Comment: you wouldn't go out of memory with a `132 by 132` matrix. see [this](http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/235282), [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/109472) and [this](http://compgroups.net/comp.soft-sys.matlab/pca-out-of-memory/887804) to calculate the required memory for pca. you can just try what I said or just subsample your data.

Answer (score 0):

Manually compute X'X (132x132) and svd on it. Or find NIPALS script.