# Find eigen vectors Using Principal Component Analysis

Tags: matlab, pca, svd

We need to find eigen vectors using PCA. We are using princomp ( matrix ). Which gives principal component co-efficient, transformed data and eigen values.

For below data :

```
2.5 2.4
0.5 0.7
2.2 2.9
1.9 2.2
3.1 3
2.3 2.7
2   1.6
1   1.1
1.5 1.6
1.1 0.9



function PCAFinder(filein)
    X = csvread(filein);

    [pc,score,latent] = princomp(X);

    pc
    transpose(pc)

end
```

Principal component co-efficient returned by above code (pc)

```
0.6779    0.7352
0.7352   -0.6779
```

Actual Eigen vector to be produced :

```
   -0.7352    -0.6779
    0.6779   -0.7352
```

How to get the above eigen vectors

Comment: If you feel I have answered your question then it is good practice to mark the question answered by clicking the tick mark next to my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The principal component co-efficient returned **is a valid eigenvector matrix** of the covariance matrix of your data. Eigenvectors are unique only up to an orthogonal transformation. For a more detailed discussion see my answer to an older SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041178/could-we-get-different-solutions-for-eigenvectors-from-a-matrix/13041400#13041400).

In this particular case, the appropriate orthogonal transformation to obtain exact equality between your matrices is to multiply your PC coefficient matrix by: `[0 1; -1 0]`