# plot principal components of iris data

Tags: matlab, plot, linear-algebra, pca

we have following command for analyse Iris data

```
load fisheriris
gscatter(meas(:,1), meas(:,2),  species,'rgb'); hold on
gscatter(meas(:,3), meas(:,4),  species,'rgb');hold on
xlabel('Sepal length');
ylabel('Sepal width');


[pc,score,latent,tsquare] = princomp(meas);
pc,latent
cumsum(latent)./sum(latent)
```

and we get result

```
pc =

    0.3614    0.6566   -0.5820    0.3155
   -0.0845    0.7302    0.5979   -0.3197
    0.8567   -0.1734    0.0762   -0.4798
    0.3583   -0.0755    0.5458    0.7537


latent =

    4.2282
    0.2427
    0.0782
    0.0238


ans =

    0.9246
    0.9777
    0.9948
    1.0000
```

and we have also figure

[image]

our task is

Please, display by plotting the projections of the data in the plan of the first two principal components with respect to the three colors of the three classes.

we can call  first two component by

```
x=pc(:,1);
y=pc(:,2);
```

but what about  plotting?please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The projected data onto the principle components is returned in the `score` variable, so the plot is simply:

```
gscatter(score(:,1), score(:,2), species, [], [], [], 'on', 'PC1', 'PC2')
title('Projected Iris data'), grid on
```

of course you could [perform the PCA yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3181851/97160) using either `EIG` or `SVD`:

```
X = meas;
X = bsxfun(@minus, X, mean(X));    % zero-centered data
[~,S,V] = svd(X,0);                % singular value decomposition

[S,ord] = sort(diag(S), 'descend');
pc = V(:,ord);                    % principle components
latent = S.^2 ./ (size(X,1)-1)    % variance explained
score = X*pc;                     % projected data
```

[image: projected_data]

Comment: so it satisfies this condition right? Please, display by plotting the projections of the data in the plan of the first two principal components with respect to the three colors of the three classes.

Comment: @datodatuashvili: yes