# Matlab error "Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options"

Tags: matlab, memory

I'm trying to run a simple example code in matlab 2013b for implementing PCA.
I have a matrix 2x88000, double, and I run a just single function with this matrix as an argument, and getting error that I'm out of memory with 70% of memory free!

I have installed 16 GB of RAM.

memory function gave:

```
Maximum possible array:     25778 MB (2.703e+10 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:     25778 MB (2.703e+10 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:      1284 MB (1.346e+09 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):     16375 MB (1.717e+10 bytes)
```

Additional information:

I have installed 3 version of matlab: 2011a, 2012b, 2013b.

Windows 7 x64

I did run profilier:

```
princomp: 0.046 s0.003 s5508.00 Kb 5508.00 Kb 0.00 Kb 1380.00 Kb
```

it used only 5,5 Mb

Comment: Type in this on the Command Window - `profile -memory on` and then start the `Profiler`, See the memory usage by your codes there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB is running out of memory but it should not be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181593/matlab-is-running-out-of-memory-but-it-should-not-be)

Answer (score 0):

Found localization of problem in question [MATLAB is running out of memory but it should not be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181593/matlab-is-running-out-of-memory-but-it-should-not-be?rq=1)

Finally for my problem Matlab supposed to allocate ~ 59 GB of memory which is not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can try the VPI add-on. it introduces a new datatype, vpi. Just declare the matrices as vpi. It should be able to manage memory problems.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic